# Cannot figure out why statement isn't printing correctly

Tags: python

I'd like this program to go to a list of URLs, see if any word in a list of words is present and then print out the URL and any of the existing words.

```
possible_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3]

for page in urllist:
    pagesource = driver.page_source
    possible_links = []
    for word in possible_words:
        if word in pagesource.lower():
            possible_links.append(word)
    print(page + ': '.join(possible_links))
```

I am expecting something like this

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72007714: word1: word2: word3
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72007715: word1: word3
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72007716: word1: word2

Instead I get this (combines the first word and the URL)

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72007714/word1: word2: word3
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72007715/word1: word3
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72007716/word1: word2

Edit: Tom is correct.  URLs do have '/' in them. I need to keep them since that is what is in URLs so I can't just replace them.  I've updated expected and actual results to reflect that

Comment: If `/` is OK, you can change the last line to: `print("%s: %s") % (page, "".join(possible_links))`.

Answer (score 0):

The join method adds the separator only between consecutive elements of the list, not before the first element of the list.  To get an extra colon and space before the first element, include that in the print statement:

```
print(page + ": " + ': '.join(possible_links))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function can handle inserting the colons for you, if you don't mind unpacking your list into the call, rather than using `str.join`:

```
print(page, *possible_links, sep=": ")
```

If you don't want to print the page out immediately in your real code (and only used it for a minimal example), then you might consider putting `page` into your list before joining it.

```
for page in whatever:
    list_to_join = [page]   # add the page to the new list as you create it
    for word in words:
        if word in something():
            list_to_join.append(word)       # optionally add some other words
    joined_string = ": ".join(list_to_join) # join everything
    # do whatever you want with the string here, rather than printing it
```